# View. Show values as Links. Strange behaviour

Tags: xpages

Xpage (listPostits.xsp) has a "View" container control, where one of the column is set "show values in this column as links".
Now, here comes "Strange behaviour".
When i work with this application on my own (developer) PC (Win XP, Chrome or IE), the Domino generate the link, which can't be really processed:

/servername/db/postit/postit.nsf/**listPostits.xsp**/onePostit.xsp?documentId=many_numbers&action=editDocument

Namely, the Bold-marked portion shouldn't be there ! This portion is the name of the XPage, where the View control is in.

When i work with the application from other PC (Mac, Firefox) then i get the correct link (the same as above but without the XPage name inbetween):

/servername/db/postit/postit.nsf/onePostit.xsp?documentId=many_numbers&action=editDocument

update:  let us leave for the moment the differencies in generated links between two machines. The first question is - why the extra portion is inserted into automatically generated link?

Comment: Could you post some code? Without it, there is no real way to tell...

Comment: listPostits.xsp is your default page on launch?

Comment: 2 Serdar: yes, listPostits.xsp is the default page on launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around i think i might have found the reason for this strange behaviour.   Namely, the "Substitution" Rules on the server side. One of them is to substitute "*/postit/all" with "/db/postit/postit.nsf/listPostits.xsp"

If i switch it off, then the Links are generated properly. Still, it's pretty strange to me that these settings influence the way Domino *generates* the links. I thought it works *on the fly* with them and those settings have nothing to do with the way how Links are generated *inside* the application.

So, the help now is needed regarding Web Site Rule Topic, but for that, i guess, i have to create another topic. But in case somebody has some good Info on this, please share it with me. I'm a bit confused at the moment :)

**Final Update**: Spent some more hours of testing and the results confirmed the initial idea.
If i open the page with the standart URL, i.e. 
`http://servername/db/postit/postit.nsf/listPostits.xsp` then everything is fine, links are generated properly. When i however open the same page with short URL `http://servername/postit/all` , then server adds the substitute URL (db/postit/postit.nsf/listPostits.xsp) to every single link he generates automatically to be used as the link to open/edit the underlying document.
Is it bug or feature ? Don't know.
As a workaround (because i want to keep simple URL's for the application) i have to manually generate links.